# Using SharePoint.Client.Search.dll to search SharePoint for specific documents, but keep getting all documents returned

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint-2013

So, currently I am working on a project and one thing that I need to do with this project is write a C# project that interacts with SharePoint 2013 Online. I have the `ClientContext` authenticated to SharePoint working and now am just trying to use Microsoft's Sharepoint.Client.Search, or more specifically use `KeywordQuery` to search SharePoint for particular documents. The problem I am having is with the returned results. In my returned results, no matter what `QueryText` I specify for my `KeywordQuery` object, I get all of the documents in SharePoint. I'm at a loss currently. Any advice?

Here is a code sample:

```
public static IEnumerable<IDictionary<string,object>> SearchSharePoint(ClientContext context, string key)
    {
        KeywordQuery keywordQuery = new KeywordQuery(context);
        keywordQuery.QueryText = key;

        SearchExecutor searchExecutor = new SearchExecutor(context);
        ClientResult<ResultTableCollection> results = searchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(keywordQuery);
        context.ExecuteQuery();
        var result = results.Value[0].ResultRows;
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: [What](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee558911.aspx) do you pass in the `key` parameter?

Comment: I've tried multiple different strings like, "Title:(title of file i know is in there)" or, just random sequences of letters. No matter the key, I get the same result.